# If I create a vector on the heap, does that mean I could access it from any other function? How?

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory

This statement creates a vector on the heap:

```
std::vector<int>* pVector = new std::vector<int>();
```

So, if I declare it in `main()` or somewhere, how can I access it in another function? For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
    
void insert(int value);

int main (){
    int n = 1;
    std::vector<int>* pVector = new std::vector<int>();
    insert(n);
    return 0;
}

void insert (int value){
    pVector->push_back(value); //ERROR "was not declared in this scope"
    std::cout << pVector[0] << "\n"; //ERROR
}
```

I'm learning on my own and heap, pointers and references are being much more complicated than I expected, so any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Pass the pointer as a parameter to `insert`.

Comment: in the same what that you passed `n`. But the type is `std::vector<int>*` instead of `int`...

Comment: Unless you create an object on thread local storage you can access them from any thread. And vector if as local object will keep its content dynamically allocated.

Comment: FWIW, a pointer to a standard container is almost never what you want.

Comment: Expanding on Nathan Oliver's comment, a large part of `std::vector`'s job (and this applies to all library containers) is to manage memory for you. By dynamically allocating  a `vector` you're taking some of that memory management back under your direct control and now you have to do work that `vector` happily did for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with heap usage.

`pVector` is simply a local variable to `main()`, so only `main()` can use it.  The only way to access the `std::vector` object from any other function is to explicitly pass in a pointer/reference to it.

You could pass it in using an input parameter, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
    
void insert(std::vector<int>& vec, int value);

int main (){
    int n = 1;

    std::vector<int>* pVector = new std::vector<int>();
    insert(*pVector, n);
    ...
    delete pVector;

    /* this works, too:
    std::vector<int> vec;
    insert(vec, n);
    ...
    */

    return 0;
}

void insert (std::vector<int>& vec, int value){
    vec.push_back(value);
    std::cout << vec[0] << "\n";
}
```

Or, you could use a global variable, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
    
std::vector<int>* pVectorToInsertInto;
void insert(int value);

int main (){
    int n = 1;

    std::vector<int>* pVector = new std::vector<int>();
    pVectorToInsertInto = pVector;
    insert(n);
    ...
    delete pVector;

    /* this woks, too:
    std::vector<int> vec;
    pVectorToInsertInto = &vec;
    insert(n);
    ...
    */

    return 0;
}

void insert (int value){
    pVectorToInsertInto->push_back(value);
    std::cout << (*pVectorToInsertInto)[0] << "\n";
}
```

In general, stay away from using global variables, if you can avoid it.

Comment: Also: there's never a reason to allocate a `std::vector` or any other container with `new`.

Comment: Beware of global variables though, they could cause crash in some cases (as in mine...)

Comment: @MooingDuck "*there's never a reason to allocate a `std::vector` or any other container with `new`*" - that depends on the situation. What you say is MOSTLY correct, but there are use cases where it is necessary to do so.

Comment: @rajdakin "*[global variables] could cause crash in some cases*" - only if you are misusing them to begin with.

Comment: This is the kind of c++ that should be buried. It amazes me how many necomers are starting with code like that.

Comment: Hi @marcinj and thanks for the comment but, would you please explain it a little bit more?.

Comment: @Ángel pointers should be wrapped into smart pointers to prevent memory leaks (UBs - undefined behaviours). This is also known as RAII idiom - in more general terms. Global objects are root of various problems, in this example its not static what makes it have external linkage - it is available in other .cpp files. Another thing is new and delete, you dont need to use it - I code for almost 15 years on one large application ....

Comment: ... and I almost never use new and delete. Its often recomended to use references instead of pointers to prevent null pointer dereferences.... Those things and many other are learnt the hardway by spending lots of time with debugger. The problem is that in C++ its very easy to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: @marcinj "*pointers should be wrapped into smart pointers to prevent memory leaks*" - OWNING pointers to CONSTRUCTED OBJECTS should be wrapped in smart pointers, to maintain proper ownership semantics at all times. But NON-OWNING pointers should not be wrapped.

Comment: @marcinj "*I code for almost 15 years on one large application and I almost never use new and delete*" - I'm on the opposite side of the spectrum.  I've spent 20 years on one large application that makes heavy use of `new`/`delete` and pointers, as it has to do a lot of asynchronous processing, so allocating data that gets queued, processed, and freed at a later time.

Comment: Ok, now I understand why this code didn't make you feel nervous:-) The funny thing is that for last 8 years I code at the same time in java ( android ) where I use `new` all the time - and watch carefully whether I dont introduce memory leaks by keeping references to components for too long. In C++ I dont remember when I last time had to track memory leaks - maybe too high memory consumption.